# Customize the theme output for the search box in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, templates, themes, preprocessor

I am trying to change the HTML that is output when I print $search_box in my page.tpl.php file. I understand the process of overriding something in drupal but I have no idea how to do it for the search box.

This is the only bit of information that I have found that seems related but I don't known how to apply it to solving my problem: http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/function/search_form/6-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check `search-block-form.tpl.php` and `search-theme-form.tpl.php` located in modules/search, as well as their preprocess functions [`template_preprocess_search_block_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess_search_block_form/6) and [`template_preprocess_search_theme_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess_search_theme_form/6).

You might also be interested in [this post](http://drupal.org/node/224183) and the pages linked from there.